# A question on fundamental matrices

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $\Phi(t)$ is a $n\times n$ matrix which elements are $C^1$ functions and $\det(\Phi(t))\neq 0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then there exists an unique matrix $A(t)$ of continuous funcions such that $\Phi(t)$ is the fundamental matrix of $x'=A(t)x$.

Can someone give me a hint on how do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Phi(t)$ is a fundamental matrix, this means
$$
\Phi'(t)=A(t)\Phi(t).
$$

Now since $\Phi(t)$ is invertible, there is no choice, you must have
$$
A(t)=\Phi'(t)\Phi(t)^{-1}.
$$